# Is it possible to describe the level sets of cos(x)cos(y) with non-trig functions?

Tags: trigonometry, plane-curves

I was looking at $-z = cos(x)cos(y)$ in math3d, and I noticed that if you take a plane -z = T (T is a slider), the intersection (or level set) kind of looks like some $x^n + y^n = r^n$.

The math3d link is [here](https://www.math3d.org/xPe9g0jk).

For example:

When z=-0.90, it looks similar to some $x^2 + y^2 = 0.5^2$.

When z=-0.25, it looks similar to some $x^4 + y^4 = 1.3^4$.

When z=-0.01, it looks similar to some $x^{20} + y^{20} = \frac{\pi}{2}^{20}$

And of course, when z=0, the level set is a square.

[image: img1]

In desmos, I tried creating a function that has this type of behavior, link [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zkxae3slwt), where the slider $n$ is supposed to vary the level set depth. I asked on reddit and someone also tried variations of $ (1-x^2/a)(1 - y^2/b) = k$. But I can't figure out if it's possible to get an exact model.

[image: img2]

If you try to solve for the level sets from $cos(x)cos(y) = c$, you get $y = cos^{-1}(c*sec(x))$. I'm not sure if you can get past this point.

Is it possible to describe the intersection of z=c and $cos(x)cos(y)$ with a non-trig function? Or is it just an illusion that $y = cos^{-1}(c*sec(x))$ looks like it can be described by some $x^n + y^n$ curve?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the variables $x,y$ in the function whose level sets you consider real variables, or do they range over the complex numbers?

Comment: @coffeemath I only tried real numbers, I haven't considered complex numbers. I still need to learn how Euler's formula works and other related formulas.

Comment: I believe there's a small mistake. When you solve for $y$ (with some assumptions), you should actually get
$$
y = \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{c}{\cos x} \right)
$$

Comment: @Matti P. I just fixed that, thanks.

Comment: A partial explanation can be found for the case when $c$ is close to 1. Let's set $c = 1 - \epsilon$ for small values of $\epsilon >0$. A Taylor expansion for $1/\cos x$ is $1+\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{5}{24}x^4 + \ldots$ ... Taking the first two terms of the Taylor expansions, we get
$$
1- \frac{1}{2}y^2 = (1-\epsilon) \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 \right)
$$
which gives us
$$
\epsilon  = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{2}y^2 - \frac{\epsilon}{2}x^2
 $$
I see a circle ...